# How to implement MapView and TableView in same page like Foursquare or Twitter?

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I am working to create an iphone app which will have a one page that has MapView in the upper and the below will be a list to display message related to that Map. It should be something looks like this screenshot ( I copied and pasted from Foursquare and Twitter app ). The text below should be like one tweet which user can click to view the reply made to that tweet.  And the annotation will be actually just one pin (unlike many pins in the screenshot).

http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/203/screenshottest.png

What I am doing now is that I used TableView  and I set tableHeaderView = mapView. 
And I then I think I will do the custom table tableViewCell . The first cell is the tweet and the cell below will be the reply.   But I am not sure if I am on the right path to do it this way.  Can anyone suggest what to do ? Or show the sample code that do something similar to my idea.

TIA,
Kong